# Will removing app from sale also end auto-renewing subscriptions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

Let's say I want to remove my app from sale, but still want existing users to keep auto-renewing their in-app subscriptions - will this work?

Answer (score 2):

According to iTunesConnect Help, it looks like you have to explicitly remove the in-app purchases from sale:

https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev7013b314c

Note: Removing an app from the App Store doesn’t automatically remove its associated in-app purchases. Customers can still download in-app purchases unless you explicitly remove them from sale. For more information, see “Removing Products from Sale” in In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

Just got off the phone with Apple:

Indeed, there is no way. If the app isn't live, auto renewals will bounce once they're due to renew.

Comment: So, if the app isn't live, auto renewals will not occur until it is live again, right ?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you have removed your app from the app store then how can you expect the auto renew happening??